# My Validate(Regions) is slow

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a WinForm C# app. It displays an image 720x360 pixels size on my `UserControl` in the `onpaint` event.

I am comparing constantly the current image with the new image that comes every 1/10 second.

I had been using `Validate()` to force the `onpaint` event to redraw the new image.

What I decided to do instead was `Invalidate` and pass regions in.

So, I compare the current image with the new image. Look for differences. Create a new rectangle object and then use the `Union` method to add the new image.

This is my code:

//I use EMGU to compare 2 images.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> _diffBetweenCurrentAndPrevious = newImage.AbsDiff(currentFrame);
```

//I enumerate through the resultant image to list the differences beyond a threshold.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 576; y++)
{                  
   for (int x = 0; x < 720; x++)
   {
      //if beyond a threshold then note it
      motionRegions.Union(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
   }
}
```

I assign the new image:

```
newImage =(Bitmap) currentFrame.Clone();
```

I then call:

```
Invalidate(motionRegions);
```

Which will call this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{       
    Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
    if (newImage != null)
    {
        pe.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(newImage, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The problem is I do not seem to be improving on response time / RAM when just re-drawing what I need to redraw.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like `motionRegions` is always going to be a full size rect. Where are you doing the comparison for differences? It's probably much slower to calculate the differences than it is to display the full image anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I missed a comment to state that if beyond a crtain threshold then keep motion change.  It is partial code.  I have to do the comparison. My issue with it is with the redraw/repaint/refresh. I cannot see how using Regions helps me as it is slow?

Comment: I agree - using regions is fairly pointless because you have to draw the whole image anyway, regions will only help if you are updating a sub-set of some child controls. Your image will never do a partial update and you waste time doing this comparison.

Comment: Hello again.  Thanks for confirming this :)